# How disable autoplay in local video into iframe into div?

Tags: html, iframe, video, playback

I have this code bellow into a html5 web page, I am using div and iframe.
when a load the page... video1.mp4 starts automatically. :(

Please, I not want video1.mp4 starts automatically.
Please, is there anybody out ther to help me?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your post.

Answer (score 0):

Give `autoplay=false` it will work .Otherwise give `autoplay=0`

Comment: My htlm5 code is: <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/video1.mp4?autoplay=false" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>.... But does not works.

Comment: Try this: <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="videos/video1.mp4?autoplay=0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>       @EuDaki